# Rendering - Render Buffer Slots

Tags: rendering

Render buffer slots show only the last rendered image instead of showing different images rendered (with different settings to compare) in each slot as done earlier in 2.7x versions.  Is it a bug or any settings I have to make in 2.80 beta?